# Photon spheres - Kerr metric

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

I'm trying to figure the photon spheres out for the Kerr BH. An article on this subject [Here](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/sciadv.aaz1310)
descripes the equation of geodesic deviation as: $$\delta r_n = e^{\gamma n}r_0$$
I don't understand where this is coming from, and I cant find it anywhere in that form. Can anyone elaborate on this.